# Entity Framework using wrong column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm extending IdentityUser and it seems at runtime EF is guessing the wrong column name for my key...

```
public class Account : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Organization> OrgMembership { get; set; }        
}
```

I don't set a sepeific ID column on my class as Microsoft Already has one down the line on IdentityUser

```
public class Organization
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }   
}

...

modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasMany<Organization>(a => a.OrgMembership)
            .WithMany();
```

This generates a table strucure using migrations perfrectly however in my controller an exception is thrown at runtime on access of the OrgMembership property. What am I doing wrong? Also how do I learn EF better/faster I feel like it wastes so much of my time with these seemingly non-intuitive errors...

```
var user = await Context.Users.FindAsync(RequestContext.Principal.Identity.GetUserId());
if(user.OrgMembership == null || user.OrgMembership.Count < 1)
{
    ...
}
```

Exception details:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2146232004
>     Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>     Source=EntityFramework
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
>          at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.LoadProperty[TItem](TItem propertyValue, String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, Boolean mustBeNull, Object wrapperObject)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.LazyLoadBehavior.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.<GetInterceptorDelegate>b__1(TProxy proxy, TItem item)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Account_86E90384E78538EC6FEAB5B02EB53C632922F2F31A50888AB46BD1C2F9BC6D40.get_OrgMembership()
>     InnerException: 
>          Class=16
>          ErrorCode=-2146232060
>          HResult=-2146232060
>          LineNumber=11
>          **Message=Invalid column name 'Account_Id'.**
>   Invalid column name 'Account_Id'.
>   Invalid column name 'Account_Id'.
>          Number=207
>          Procedure=""
>          Server=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB
>          Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>          State=1
>          StackTrace:
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>               at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>               at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>          InnerException:

Comment: Use `Map` after WithMany to map the left and the right key. I think this is cause of your  problem

Comment: Have tried that with no luck. Also tried overriding the Id property on Account and adding KeyAttribute to it. Didn't work either :/

Comment: Add `WithMany(x => x.Accounts)`